# :empty and :blank with comment inside

Tags: html, css, sass

I am using `:empty` and `:blank`. They work fine, but I have a case where AngularJS is injecting comments inside a `div`, and those will not work anymore. Is there something I can do to make `:empty` and `:blank` work with comments?

Comment: Wanna mention that together with comment there is one space.

Answer (score 1):

This issue also happens with angular, these are placeholders for not visible elements (ex: ngIf...)

strating with CSS 4, `:empty` starts ignoring comments...
https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-empty-pseudo

> comments, processing instructions, and other nodes must not affect whether an element is considered empty or not.

as a workaround, for now, since `:has` support is growing (as of writing available everywhere except Mozilla behind a flag), you can do something like:

```css
:not(:has(*)) {
  display: none;
}
```

NOTE: this works as long as you don't have stray text inside the element.
ex:

```html
<div class="container">
text
</div>
```

here `.container:not(:has(*))` is matched, however

```html
<div class="container">
<span>text</span>
</div>
```

here `.container:not(:has(*))` is not matched

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that you can do... try to have a look at: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production paying attention to the `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);`...

Generally is not a good idea *the use of `:empty` (or something else) pseudoselector with the goal of selecting empty elements* because that selectors are sensible to everything, whitespace included.
There is an example:

```css
div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: cyan;
  margin: 5px;
}

div:empty { display: none; }
```

```html
<div>

</div>
<div> </div>

<!-- just this -->
<div></div>
```

#### EDITED

a possible workaround could be creating a custom directive that does this for you, but, of course, it should be manually added to the elements where you want to know if they are empty or not. Here is an example:

```js
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .directive('emptyClass', function() {
    return function postLink(iScope, iElement, iAttrs) {
      
      function updateOnChanges() {
        var classname = iAttrs.emptyClass;
        
        var hasContent = iElement.children().length > 0 ||
            iElement.text().trim().length > 0;
        
        if(hasContent) {
          return iElement.removeClass(classname);
        }
        
        return iElement.addClass(classname);
      }
      
      iElement[0].addEventListener(
        "DOMSubtreeModified", updateOnChanges, false
      );
      updateOnChanges();
    }
  })
;
```

```css
.is-empty { background: cyan; display: block; min-height: 20px; margin: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="test">
  <h1 empty-class="is-empty">  </h1>
  <h1 empty-class="is-empty"></h1>

  <h1 empty-class="is-empty">
    <!-- ng-if: "oh Yeah" -->
  </h1>
  
  <h1 empty-class="is-empty"> Hello World </h1>
  <h1 empty-class="is-empty"><span>Hello World</span></h1>
</section>
```

Comment: $compileProvider will hide the information, but comments are still displayed :(

Comment: yes, as I said, there are few things that you can do... this is how angular 1x was made.

Comment: hmm, can I use ng-cloak to add a class to the div, instead of commenting it out?

Comment: probably a custom directive could be the best idea, have a look on my last edits.

Comment: That works fine, even though there are some small issues, thanks a lot.

Comment: what issues you found?